# What are the valid types of `attr` in a Bazel rule definition

Tags: bazel

The [documentation](https://docs.bazel.build/versions/master/skylark/rules.html#attributes) shows this:

```
sum = rule(
    implementation = _impl,
    attrs = {
        "number": attr.int(default = 1),
        "deps": attr.label_list(),
    },
)
```

There's an `int` and a `label_list`. But what are the other options? What other types can be rule attributes? `attr.string()` also appears to exist. What else is there?

Comment: Thanks for the feedback! We'll improve this section in the documentation.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can find a complete list here: https://docs.bazel.build/versions/master/skylark/lib/attr.html

This includes:

```
bool
int
int_list
label
label_keyed_string_dict
label_list
license
output
output_list
string
string_dict
string_list
string_list_dict
```